# How to return an Array in an struct?

Tags: struct, solidity, smartcontracts, hardhat

I wrote a contract that keeps an array of the "wRequest", which is the type of a constructer I wrote. But when I add something to the list and try to return it, I can only get the arguments that are not arrays.
what seems to be problem?

**Contract :**

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;


contract s {

    WRequest[] public WRequestList;

    struct WRequest {
        address receiver;
        address[] tokenAddresss;
        uint256[] amounts;
        uint approved;
        
    }

    function submitWithdrawRequest(address receiver, address[] memory tokenAddresss, uint256[] memory amounts) public {
        WRequest memory request = WRequest(receiver, tokenAddresss, amounts, 0);
        WRequestList.push(request);

    }

}
```

deploy.js

```
const hre = require("hardhat");

async function main() {

  const Lock = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("s");
  const lock = await Lock.deploy();
  const [owner, account1 ,account2] = await ethers.getSigners();

  await lock.deployed();
  console.log("deployed")
  await lock.submitWithdrawRequest(owner.address, [account1.address], [7])
  const list = await lock.WRequestList(0);
  console.log(list);
}

main().catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exitCode = 1;
});
```

**Result**

```
[
  '0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266',
  BigNumber { value: "0" },
  receiver: '0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266',
  approved: BigNumber { value: "0" }
]
```

It only includes the receiver address and approved, and not the array of tokenAddresss and amounts.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function for this

```
function getWRequest(uint _index) public view returns(WRequest memory) {
   return WRequestList[_index];
}
```